# BigDecimal with 2 fraction after decimal point?

Tags: java, jsf, biginteger

I'd like to have a BigDecimal formatted with 2 decimals after the decimal point. Always.

Based on some boolean checks, I sometimes return a BigDecimal.ZERO;
In this case, the JSF page just displays "0", although I set `<f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2"/>`.

I do not understand this, but nevertheless how can I enforce 2 digits else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

there are 2 ways of doing this

you can use the built in `BigDecimal` function

```
myBigDecimal.SetScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

This returns a big decmial with 2 digits past the decimal and also rounds up.(there are also other rounding methods)

OR

you could use jsf convertNumber Tag

```
<f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2" />
```

Comment: just keep in mind that if you need to round up, the `setScale` will take care of this. Just using the `convertNumber` will not.

Comment: yes great, that works on zero: BigDecimal.ZERO.SetScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); ...what is really strange: the jsf convertNumber tag does NOT work on the BigDecimal.ZERO. No way ???

Comment: You indeed have to be very careful regarding to rounding. The convert number tag does rounding but it seems to use RoundingMode HALF_EVEN. Therefore it will round 1.115 to 1.12 but also 1.125 will become 1.12
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN

Comment: @membersound i believe the reason that `convertNumber` does not work for  `BigDecimal.ZERO` is because it is a static.

Answer (score 1):

Try formatting the number like this:

```
    <h:outputText value="#{myBean.bd1}">
        <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00" />
    </h:outputText>
```

Note: Please also pay attention to the warnings regarding to rounding in the accepted answer.

Comment: I've tested this before posting and it does work for BigDecimal.ZERO, too. I've used JSF2 and tomcat 7.

Comment: That's really strange. I use a method to return the Zero: `class myBean() { public BigDecimal getAmount() {return BigDecimal.ZERO; }}` ...could you check if it does also work for you when refering with `value="#{myBean.getAmount()}"`?

Comment: This is really strange. It does not work using JSF2 + JBoss AS7. Can you confirm the following code really works for you?    `private BigDecimal tmp = BigDecimal.ZERO;
   <h:outputText value=" #{service.tmp}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00" />
   </h:outputText>` ...then I have to look into tomcat if the problem is server-related...

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
<af:convertNumber maxIntegerDigits="3" maxFractionDigits="2"   minFractionDigits="2" pattern="###.##" />
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?